# If $a$ is a complex number and b is a real number, then prove that the equation $a\bar z+\bar a z+b=0$ is a straight line passing though origin.

Tags: complex-numbers

Generally, $z\bar z +\bar a z + a\bar z+b=0$ represents a circle

The lack of the term $z\bar z$ confirms that it is a straight line.

But we still have the term b, which is a real number and isn’t necessarily zero, then how do we prove that it passes though the origin?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is stated correctly? For $b \ne 0$ is $a\bar z+\bar a z+b=0$ a line that definitely does *not* pass through the origin.

Comment: @MartinR I wrote it the way it was.

Comment: Then the statement is wrong: $z=0$ satisfies the equation $a\bar z+\bar a z+b=0$ if and only if $b=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is slightly misstated since the word "variable" is missing. It should be like this

> If $a$ is a fixed complex number and $b$ is a **variable** real number, then prove that the equation $a\bar z+\bar a z+b=0$ is a straight line passing though origin.

Write $\,a = u+vi\,$ and $\,z = x+yi.\,$ Then
$$ a\bar z+\bar a z = (ux+vy) + (vx-uy)i  $$ and if this number is equal to a real number $\,b\,$
then $\,vx-uy=0,\,$ which is the equation
of a line through the origin.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
a\bar{z}&=|a||z|\angle \left(arg(a)-arg(z)\right)\\
\bar{a}z&=|a||z|\angle \left(arg(z)-arg(a)\right)\\
\\
a\bar{z}+\bar{a}z+b&=2|a||z|\cos{\left(arg(a)-arg(z)\right)}+b
\end{aligned}
$$

Some interpretations:

$z$ is a set of points in the complex plane such that $\vec{Oz}\cdot\vec{Oa}=\frac{b}{2}$.

$z$ lies on a line that is perpendicular to $\vec{Oa}$

$z=\frac{ab}{2|a|^{2}}+i(ma), m\in\mathbb{Z}$

The line only goes through origin if $b=0$